# AWS CodePipeline with laravel app not showing

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I deployed my laravel app from bitbucket to the aws codepipeline. I attached the codepipeline to an already running environment.

The previous zip version was working normally but when I upload the version from pipeline it just displaying the white/blank page.

The process in CodePipeline from source to deploy works with no errors at all. Is there any checklist or something I should review to make this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can download the app version produced by the CP, and inspect if it has all files required.

Comment: I will try thank you for now

Comment: I'm also getting status 500 @Marcin and when I try to download a version file I can't open it then. Text edit - zero bytes

Comment: Can be a problem that It just handled last commit and uploaded it ?

Comment: Do you have a build stage in your CP? For example with CodeBuild which will download any dependencies (submodules), package to zip for deployment into EB?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have this. Just looking into file structure trough ssh and there is .env file missing and also node_modules missing

Comment: Seems then you should have build stage to fill in the gaps. Maybe, alternatively could also use `.ebextensions` in your project to setup up all these dependencies. This way maybe can avoid build stage.

Comment: do you have any suggestions what should I include into .ebextensions ?? thanks

Comment: Don't know exactly. Maybe [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html#php-laravel-tutorial-configure) have some useful info.